# ExoPlayer: play sound in the background with a video file

Tags: android, android-service, exoplayer

Playing a video, and when the app goes to background it should continue playing the audio, and when I reopen it should resume the video respecting where we are in audio.

I'm using exoplayer in a service, I was able to play the audio in background, but when I do the same for video, the audio is playing but when I come back to the app the video is just a black screen, and if I repeat (going to background and coming back to app) the step again it will continue playing video.

As I understood, exoplayer is buffering next frames and the player view got stuck unable to render all frames at once.

I have one instance of exoplayer:

```
public class ExoPlayerWrapper {

private static SimpleExoPlayer exoPlayer;

public static SimpleExoPlayer getExoPlayer(Context context){

    if(exoPlayer == null){
        exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, new DefaultTrackSelector());
    }

    return exoPlayer;
}

public static void release() {
    if(exoPlayer != null) {
        exoPlayer.release();
        exoPlayer = null;
    }
}
}
```

The service runs once the view is in foreground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I did it with, in on pause set playerView.setPlayer(null) and in on resume set playerView.setPlayer(exoplayer_instance)

Comment: If your `exoplayer_instance` is defined in your `Service` and not in your `Activity`, how are you passing it to `playerView.setPlayer()`? I'm trying to figure this out right now but I'm probably missing something obvious since I'm new to Android development

Comment: my exoplayer instance is singleton